# jQuery target first item not working

Tags: jquery

When I use `jQuery("input[title='Clone']")[0]` it returns the item I am looking but when I try `jQuery("input[title='Clone']")[0].after( "<h1>test</h1>" );` it gives me a TypeError undefined is not a function.

How do I target the first item on the page instead of all of them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is because your syntax is accessing the native DOM element within the jQuery selector and then attempting to use jQuery methods on it.

To get the first element of a selector via jQuery use `:first` or `.first()` or `.eq(0)`:

```
jQuery("input[title='Clone']:first").after("<h1>test</h1>");
jQuery("input[title='Clone']").first().after("<h1>test</h1>");
jQuery("input[title='Clone']").eq(0).after("<h1>test</h1>");
```

Comment: Also `jQuery("input[title='Clone']").slice(0, 1).after("<h1>test</h1>");`. Lots of options.

Answer (score 2):

`jQuery("input[title='Clone']")[0]` will return the required dom object but you can not use native jquery methods on them. You need to use `.eq()` or `.first()` selector here:

```
jQuery("input[title='Clone']").eq(0).after( "<h1>test</h1>" );//or jQuery("input[title='Clone']:eq(0)")
```

or

```
jQuery("input[title='Clone']").first().after( "<h1>test</h1>");//or jQuery("input[title='Clone']:first")
```